# Pass template to child component dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-template

I would like to load the content of my page dynamically depending on the active navigation point.

```
export class Sub_navigation_item {
    constructor(
      public title: string,
      public templateName: string
    ) {}
  }
```

I therefore have a navigation item with the ID from an ng-template.
I would like to pass the content to a child component based on this ID.

These are my navigation items:

```
this.navbarItems = [
        new Sub_navigation_item('General', 'generalTemplate'),
        new Sub_navigation_item('Actions', 'actionTemplate'),
        new Sub_navigation_item('Inactivity', 'inactivityTemplate')
];
```

Here is my template for the general page:

```
<ng-template #generalTemplate>
    <div class="generalContent">
        <div>
         hello world
       </div>
  </ng-template>
```

And here is my child component:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-lg-8">
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="content"></ng-container>
```

TS:

```
import { Sub_navigation_item } from './../../../../models/sub_navigation_item';
import {
    Component,
    OnInit,
    Input,
    TemplateRef
  } from '@angular/core';

  import { RestApiService } from './../../../../services/api/rest-api.service';
  import { Actionevent_Type } from 'src/app/models/actionEvent';

  @Component({
    // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
    selector: 'bot-detail-page',
    templateUrl: './bot-detail-page.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./bot-detail-page.component.scss']
  })
  export class BotDetailPageComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() title: string;
    @Input() content: TemplateRef<any>;

    constructor(private restApiService: RestApiService) {
    }

ngOnInit() {
}
```

}

I am trying to create the content via ngFor:

```
<bot-detail-page [title]="navbarItem.title" [content]="navbarItem.templateName"> 
            
</bot-detail-page>
```

If i pass 'generalTemplate'to the [content] it works but navbarItem.templateName doesnt work.

Comment: you seem to be instantiating your navigation items with strings only (`new Sub_navigation_item('Actions', 'actionTemplate'),`), shouldn't the second argument be a variable holding the template?

Comment: it was an error. I fixed it.

Comment: `Sub_navigation_item.templateName` is `string`, and `BotDetailPageComponent.content` expects a `TemplateRef`, that must be the issue

Answer (score 1):

In parent component you need to have all the templates in `.html`.
Then in the parent component's class you need to get references to all these templates, one of the options is to select them via `ViewChild` property decorator. And then you can pass these templates into child component's `content` input.

in parent component's class:

```
export class ParentComponent {    
  @ViewChild('generalTemplate') gt: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('actionTemplate') at: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

you can introduce any intermediate logic to select target template (here we just pass directly `gt`):

```
<bot-detail-page [title]="navbarItem.title" [content]="gt">
```

Comment: Thanks, but i will add the content dynamically so i will pass it as an object property to my Sub_navigation_item.

And if i do this it doesnt work.

Comment: Ah I have to add the array creating stuff into the nfAfterViewInit lifecycle hook to wait until the page is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

As @D Pro mentioned in the comment ngTemplateOutlet expects template reference instead of string. I would sugggest you to create directive to get TemplateRef of element somethink like this:

**sub-navigation.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive,Input,TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appSubNavigation]'
})
export class SubNavigationDirective {
  @Input() public title:string;
  constructor(public template: TemplateRef<any>) { }

}
```

Then in parent component html place directive on the ng-template

```
<ng-template appSubNavigation title="General">
    <div class="generalContent">
        <div>
         hello world
       </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>

<app-bot-details *ngIf="navbarItem?.length"

[title]="navbarItem[0].title" [content]="navbarItem[0].template"
> 
</app-bot-details>
```

In component ts use ViewChildren to get all the defined templateRef

```
@ViewChildren(SubNavigationDirective)  set subNavigation(ref:QueryList<SubNavigationDirective>){
    this.navbarItem = ref.toArray();
  };
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nav-items?file=src/app/app.component.ts)